# Do commercial firewalls have API / Remote CLI?

Tags: api, security, command-line-interface, firewall, checkpoint

I mean firewalls like Checkpoint, Fortigate, sonicWALL etc.
Do they have have API or Remote CLI ?
can i, for example, send them a remote call to filter in\out a certain port?
I Just want to know if that's possible, if you have examples that's awesome, but evena  simple "yes, Checkpoint and soincwall does that" are great!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I only have some experience with Fortigate-firewalls. They usually have SSH.

This means you could use a command like this:

```
ssh <hostname_or_IP> -t "echo 'hello world'"
```

to sumbit your new rules to your firewall.